# How can I bold upcoming text in Etherpad?

Tags: etherpad

Is there a way that one can bold upcoming text in Etherpad?
For example, I want to press ctrl+b, and start typing in Bold. Then press ctrl+b again and go to normal formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a plugin to enable this behaviour:

Install the sticky attributes plugin on your Etherpad deployment

https://github.com/JohnMcLear/ep_sticky_attributes

Enjoy